# Алгоритм посторения cdn и его реализация

Tags: nginx, dns, bind, geoip, cdn

Нужно реализовать сеть доствки контента (cdn). Есть основной сервер (250.250.250.250) где реализовн фронтэнд+бэкэнд,который привязан к домену mydomain.com Есть 3 прокси-серврера (111.111.111.111,222.222.222.222 и 333.333.333.333), которые кэшируют весь фронтэнд, а динамические запросы идут на основной севрер. То есть к примеру обращение к серверу 111.111.111.111 статический контетнт грузится с него, а динамические запросы идут на 250.250.250.250. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при обращении к домену mydomain.com, к которому привязан сервер 250.250.250.250 шел запрос на 11.111.111.111 или 222.222.222.222 или 333.333.333.333 в зависимости от географической близости. С помощью каких утилит это можно реализовать и как?
Все сервера на nginx
Конфиг основного сервера 250.250.250.250

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html/main/prod/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;
    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include fastcgi_params;
    }


    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
```

Код прокси кэшируемого сервера 111.111.111.111

```
proxy_cache_path /var/www/cache levels= keys_zone=mycache:150m;



server {
#устанавливаем дефолтовый флаг, не кэшировать
set $cached 0;
listen 111.111.111.111:80;
#нужно чтобы отдавать красивую 500Ашипку с себя
error_page 502 503 504 509 /500.html;
#если где-то что-то забыли, то будет работать схема прозрачного проксирования
error_page 404 = @nocached;

expires epoch;
root /var/www/html;

location = /500.html {
}

#динамику будем брать с frontend и если отсутствует, то скачивать
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|gz|zip|flv|rar|wmv|avi|css|swf|png|htc|ico|mpeg|mpg|txt|mp3|mov|js)$ {
expires 1d;
error_page 404 = @fetch;
}

#кэшируем статику на себя
location @fetch {
proxy_pass http://250.250.250.250:80;
proxy_store on;
proxy_temp_path /var/www/_fetch;
proxy_set_header Host mydomain;
proxy_set_header If-Modified-Since "";
}

#для зарегистрированных проксируем прозрачно
location @nocached {
proxy_pass http://250.250.250.250:80;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

#гостям проксируем и кэшируем
location @cached {
proxy_pass http://250.250.250.250;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_cache mycache;
proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 304 5m;
proxy_cache_key "$request_method|$http_if_modified_since|$http_if_none_match|$host|$request_uri";
proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
}

#иначе морда домена не будет работать
location = / {
return 404;
}

location / {
#если нет нашей куки
if ($http_cookie !~ "userid" ) {
set $cached 1;
}

if ($request_method = POST) {
set $cached 0;
}

if ($request_method != GET) {
set $cached 0;
}

if ($cached = 1) {
error_page 404 405 502 504 = @cached;
break;
}

if ($cached = 0) {
error_page 404 405 502 504 = @nocached;
break;
}

}

}
```

Comment: Проще пойти к провайдеру CDN. Ngenix, Cloud Flare и т.п.

Comment: Я в курсе, но нужно построить именно свою cdn.  Вообще насколько я понял, нужно на основном сервере поднять dns-сервер, который будет принимать запросы и отдавать нужный кэширующий сервер. Но вопрос в том, как и с помощью чего сделать балансировщик